# JSZip: Checking if a zip folder contains a specific file

Tags: javascript, typescript, jszip

I currently have the following code:

```
zip.folder("courses").forEach(function (relativePath, file) {
    if (!file.dir) {
        promises.push(zip.file(file.name).async("string"));
    }
});
```

But I believe this assumes that the zip contains the "courses" folder, how do I check whether or not the zip contains a "courses" folder before the forEach loop? Thanks!

Comment: If `zip.folder()` returns an array, you can check `zip.folder("courses").length`

Comment: It's asynchronous though, where would I check the length?

Comment: Have you tried [`.folder(regex)`](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/folder_regex.html)?

Comment: I can't seem to get a length property with that either?

Comment: Did you use `.folder(/courses/)`? If no array is returned, the folder does not exist at that instance of `JSZip`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with the function `folder()` like:

```
var zip = new JSZip();    
if(zip.folder(/courses/).length > 0) {
    // Folder exists
} else {
    // Folder doesn't exist
}
```

`folder()` returns an array, see the [documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_regex.html). It is possible with `file()` too.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific file, you can try by the file name like following way.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
...................
if(zip.file(/csv/).length > 0 ){
  // Do something
} 
else if(zip.file(/pdf/).length > 0) {
  // Do something 
}
```